# "Data source name not found and no default driver specified" for creating access connection

Tags: c#, ms-access, ado.net, odbc, oledb

This is my connection to an access database in .NET:

```
OdbcConnection conn = new OdbcConnection("Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};Dbq=" + path + "\\Access.mdb;Uid=;Pwd=;");
```

And I got this problem:

```
base {System.Data.Common.DbException} = {"ERROR [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified"}
```

I have tried couple of database connection strings from here: http://www.connectionstrings.com/access but none of them working.

Any suggestions for this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you using windows 7?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an easy way to get the connection string, try it as follow:

- Create a text file and change it's extension to `.udl`.
- Open the new file by double click it and choose to open it with any text editor, notepad for example.
- In the opened window, choose your provider and your database and click OK.
- Open this file with notepad as a text and you will find the connectoin string inside it.

See [**This**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa140076%28v=office.10%29.aspx) for more details.

Comment: no, I could not find the connection string inside the notepad

Comment: What do you do if there isn't an Access provider in the list?

Comment: @RobSedgwick - Try to install "Access Database Engine 2010" from this link http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255, it should appear after that.

Comment: Use OleDbConnection with this connection string.

Answer (score 1):

as you can see in the same site you have linked above, the default way to connect to access database is specifying the `Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0` Provider:

```
Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\mydatabase.mdb;User Id=admin;Password=;
```

does this work and if not what kind of errors do you get?

Comment: [System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException] = {"ERROR [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified"}

Comment: Use OleDbConnection with this connection string.

Answer (score 0):

First, is `path` a valid field?

Second, try to output the String you are using to connect with the database file, as a sanity check. Make sure the output string matches what you are expecting, and that the file specified exists.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

http://www.connectionstrings.com/

More specifically this one

http://www.connectionstrings.com/access

I would change your code to the following:

```
OdbcConnectionStringBuilder sb = new OdbcConnectionStringBuilder();
sb.Driver = "Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)";
sb.Add("Dbq", "C:\\info.mdb");
sb.Add("Uid", "Admin");
sb.Add("Pwd", "pass!word1");
OdbcConnection con = new OdbcConnection(sb.ConnectionString);
```

Answer (score 0):

web.config add

```
add name="odbcConnectionString"
    connectionString="Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=|DataDirectory|info.mdb; "
    providerName="System.Data.OleDb"
```