# Create Connection to .accdb Access File

Tags: java, odbc

I've been on this class for a few days now searching the web trying to find a solution. What I am trying to do here is connect to a Access 2010 database with an extension `.accdb` I have been successful connecting to older databases with extensions of `.mdb` but not `.accdb`

I have tried uninstalling Office and re-installing it for x64 versions and then installing the Access x64 tools. The error I received when I use the below code is as follows:

```
java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified
```

At this point I have no idea what could be causing this. To point out, I need to have this setup with no DSN specified because this may run on multiple machines and I do not want to have to setup and maintain a DSN on each.

```
String database = "jdbc:odbc:DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=C:\\Users\\Brandon\\Dropbox\\Work\\Angent Profiles\\Database1.accdb;";
Connection conn = null;

    try {
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(database, "", "");
    } catch (SQLException SQLE) {
        System.out.println("ERROR: " + SQLE);
    }
```

Any advice on this would be grateful.

EDIT:

```
C:\Windows\system32>java -version
java version "1.7.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_25-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.25-b01, mixed mode)

C:\Windows\system32>
```

EDIT:

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.15.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Brandon\Dropbox\Work\Angent Profiles\Database1.accdb;Persist Security Info=False



String database = "jdbc:odbc:DRIVER={Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.15.0 (*.mdb, *.accdb)};Data Source=C:\\Users\\Brandon\\Dropbox\\Work\\Angent Profiles\\Database1.accdb;";
```

Comment: Can you post your JVM string (`java -version`)?

Comment: Edited to include JVM string

Comment: Try the trick in [the answer to this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8201489/data-source-name-not-found-and-no-default-driver-specified-for-creating-access) and see if that connection string matches what you're using.

Comment: Negative, even though the connection string was different it still did not work.

Comment: For giggles, post the new one?

Comment: Same error with new string

Comment: Yes, I understood that. Can you post the new string?

Comment: Maybe I did thee new string wrong?

Comment: Try dropping the trailing semicolon and/or adding the `Persist Security Info` clause.

Comment: Like this? `"jdbc:odbc:Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.15.0;Data Source=C:\\Users\\Brandon\\Dropbox\\Work\\Angent Profiles\\Database1.accdb;Persist Security Info=False"`

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to run a 32 bit JRE to connect to access databases. From my understanding there is currently no 64 bit access ODBC driver available.