# How to connect microsoft access database to jsp tomcat?

Tags: java, jsp, ms-access, tomcat, database-connection

I want to make a login form on my page by accessing database. Here is the connect code

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=utf-8" language="java" import="java.sql.*" errorPage="" %>
<%
    Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=" + application.getRealPath("WEB-INF/travDB.accdb"));
    Statement st = con.createStatement(1004,1008);
%>
```

When I tried to login, there was an error saying

```
type Exception report

message An exception occurred processing JSP page /Advance/Course1/connect.jsp at line 4

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /Advance/Course1/connect.jsp at line 4

1: <%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=utf-8" language="java" import="java.sql.*" errorPage="" %>
2: <%
3:  Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
4:  Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=" + application.getRealPath("WEB-INF/travDB.accdb"));
5:  Statement st = con.createStatement(1004,1008);
6: %>


Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:568)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:455)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)

root cause

javax.servlet.ServletException: java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doHandlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:912)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:841)
    org.apache.jsp.Advance.JSP.Project.JSP_005fH2Soal2.JSP_005fH2Soal2_005fT213.doLogin_jsp._jspService(doLogin_jsp.java:119)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)

root cause

java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified
    sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.createSQLException(Unknown Source)
    sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.standardError(Unknown Source)
    sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.SQLDriverConnect(Unknown Source)
    sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcConnection.initialize(Unknown Source)
    sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
    java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.jsp.Advance.JSP.Project.JSP_005fH2Soal2.JSP_005fH2Soal2_005fT213.doLogin_jsp._jspService(doLogin_jsp.java:72)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
```

I already made WEB-INF folder inside folder Course1, and connect.jsp is also on folder Course1.
What should I do?

I'm using Windows 7 Professional 64bit, and tomcat version 7.0, jre 6 64bit

Comment: Excellent start. Now, is the 64-bit version of the Access Database Engine installed?

Comment: @GordThompson how to check that?

Comment: `Windows Control Panel` > `Administrative Tools` > `Data Sources (ODBC)`. On the "Drivers" tab do you see "Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)" listed?

Comment: @GordThompson not listed on drivers tab. but listed on user dsn tab

Answer (score 2):

Are you using **32-bit MS Access Database**?
You mentioned you have **64-bit OS ans JRE also 64-bit**, but if you have 32-bit Access database then above mentioned exception occur. [See this similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10289655/1031945).

**You can not directly connect to a 32-bit Access ODBC driver from a 64-bit program.**
While Microsoft distributes 32 bit ODBC Microsoft Access Drivers with Windows (32 & 64 bit), it does not distribute 64 bit MsAccess drivers with Windows 64. There is a [64 bit Access ODBC Driver](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=13255) available from Microsoft. There are some issues with downloading and installing the 64 bit MS Access driver.
[Refer this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10290227/1031945)

Similar Posts

- [Post 1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16626301/1031945)
- [Post 2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18245423/1031945)
- [Not similar but helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9543722/1031945)

Comment: there's already *.mdb on Microsoft access with *.accdb . should I add again?